# Can't save custom field on registration page

Tags: custom-field, hooks, profiles

I have a WordPress Multisite build and I'm trying to add a custom field to the admin user registration form but the metadata isn't saving in the initial form: after I create the user, I can go to the new profile page and the custom field will save.

Here is my function to add the custom field, which does display on the registration page (/wp-admin/user-new.php).

```
/**
 * Add custom fields to WordPress account registration
 *
 * @param $user
 */
function add_rm_tenant_info( $user ) { ?>
    <h3>Rent Manager Tenant Information</h3>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="accountNumber">Account Number</label></th>
            <td>
                <input type="number" name="accountNumber" id="accountNumber" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'accountNumber', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
                <span class="description">This number is used to connect the tenant's information from Rent Manager to their WordPress profile.</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'add_rm_tenant_info' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'add_rm_tenant_info' );
add_action( "user_new_form", "add_rm_tenant_info" );
```

And here is my function to save the field. It doesn't seem to work on the registration page, but will save after I create the user and edit the profile.

```
/**
 * Saves custom fields
 *
 * @param $user_id
 * @return bool
 */
function save_rm_tenant_info( $user_id ) {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
        return false;
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'accountNumber', $_POST['accountNumber'] );
}
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_rm_tenant_info' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_rm_tenant_info' );
add_action( 'user_register', 'save_rm_tenant_info' );
add_action( 'profile_update', 'save_rm_tenant_info' );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the **show_user_profile**, **edit_user_profile**, **personal_options_update**, and **edit_user_profile_update** hooks.

You can use the following code format adding additional fields in User section.

```
 add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields' );
 add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields' );
 function extra_user_profile_fields( $user ) { ?>
<h3><?php _e("Extra profile information", "blank"); ?></h3>

<table class="form-table">
<tr>
    <th><label for="address"><?php _e("Address"); ?></label></th>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="address" id="address" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'address', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php } ?>
```

For Saving the usemeta's in database,

```
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields' );

function save_extra_user_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) ) { 
       return false; 
    }
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'address', $_POST['address'] );
}
```

There are also several blog posts available on the subject that might be helpful:

[link 1](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/09/10/adding-and-using-custom-user-profile-fields)

[link 2](https://bavotasan.com/2009/adding-extra-fields-to-the-wordpress-user-profile/)

Hope this will helpful for you.

Comment: I have those added already, see my last 4 lines of code.

Comment: yes, but why you added the extra function calls? like:- add_action( 'user_register', 'save_rm_tenant_info' );

add_action( 'profile_update', 'save_rm_tenant_info' );

Comment: Because those are the hooks for editing profile pages.

Comment: but you don't need it,I used the same example it's working for me perfectly.

Comment: Are you on a Multisite platform? Which user resigtartion page are you on?

Comment: you can check this link for your requirement [link 1](https://foxland.fi/user-meta-in-wordpress-multisite/), [link 2](https://gist.github.com/samikeijonen/63d1bd862adc69786936), [link 3](http://wpadminuicustomize.com/blog/how-to-customize-for-register-form-for-multisite/)